# HSV conversion with cvCvtColor() issue

Tags: c, opencv, threshold, hsv

I'm trying convert RGB image to HSV with the function cvCvtColor(), but the results are unexpected. For example, white are converted to something near to red.

```
        cvCvtColor(img, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
        cvSplit( hsv, h, s, v, NULL );
        cvInRangeS(h,cvScalar(0,0,0,0),cvScalar(20,0,0,0),imgthresh);  
        cvShowImage("image", img);
        cvShowImage("hsv", hsv);
        cvShowImage("threshold", imgthresh);
```

Is the image converted correctly and only displayed wrong? 
And about the threshold, the better way to do this is using the 3 channels or only the hue?
I want track red objects.
Sorry about the english.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cvShowImage will always expect RGB values (Or BGR, I am not sure). So, when you convert to HSV, it's expected that the color are shown different. Using this [rgb to hsv conversor](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm), you can see that white  - in RGB represented as (255,255,255) - is converted to (0,0,100%) in HSV. As you are saying that the displayed color of white is red, I suspect that cvShowImage is really expecting BGR by default.

Comment: `cvShowImage()` and `cv::imshow()` expect BGR channel ordering.